Timezone defaults to UTC
I have an application that is running as expected. Many portion of the application displays DateTime. I am using jodatime library.
After adding features to the application, default timezone changed to UTC.
I was wondering why this happen because I did not explicitly set timezone, I am initializing DateTime with, DateTime.now() or DateTime(millis). I know I should set timezones explicitly, but what could be any reasons for jodatime's default timezone to change?

please clarify the situation because UTC is constant regardless of your location by definition, it is Universal Time Coordinated.  If you said you used EST and moved to PST I could see why your DateTime is different, since PST is 3 hours behind but that would be expected, no?

@HukeLau_DABA Yeah. UTC is the same anywhere in the world.
What I was trying to ask for help here is that all my DateTime representation in the application's UI was using UTC instead of my current timezone like it was for the previous version of the application.
Anyway, I already answered the question. If you can edit, help me revise the question to help others that might have the same problem.

Do not call DateTime.now() before application::onCreate. This will result to a null default TimeZone. If you somehow initialize a DateTime variable in an application class like this:
    private var dateTime: DateTime = DateTime.now()

Delay its call after or inside application::onCreate, something like this:
    private lateinit var dateTime: DateTime

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        dateTime = DateTime.now()
    }

